# Toggle Model Builder paths on and off using Boolean - ArcMap 10.5

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, modelbuilder, calculate-values, boolean

I have a program that uses an iterate over a multivariable to run checks for different values, but it would be really nice to just be able to toggle the values on and off depending on what you are searching for.

The model builder image has Toggle_var_1 referencing to a variable inside of the Table of Variables multivalue. The goal is to find a way to set the Toggle_var booleans as True or False and then run the model only with values checked as true.

The booleans themselves can't be used because they are only true or false, but the variables in Table of Variables are strings that are used to search a database, so I am trying to find a way to control the string values using the boolean ones so when someone runs it from the ArcMap they only need to tick boxes to choose what gets searched.

(Hopefully this is clear enough, if not I am more than happy to rephrase/answer questions)

[image]

Comment: You need to show us this code you have developed and how you are using it.

Comment: Sam, I've deleted your code as 1 you cannot export iterators to python and two its a red herring. What you need to do is edit your question and show what you are doing in the Make Query Layer tool. You have made the output of the iterator a precondition to the Make Query tool, I know this as the line is dotty. But your Year+Variable which I assume is the boolean is an input to a parameter because the line is solid. Or it could be an SQL expression, no one can tell. What are the 3 Toggle_var_x they don't seem to be doing anything?

Comment: That's the thing, The Query is irrelevant, it can be any tool, I am trying to make a way to turn a value on and off. The Toggle_var_1 is a boolean that I want to control when you run it in the ArcMap workspace. Basically the option to only use certain values when you run the program that you can tick on and off when you run the tool.

Comment: In that case the toggle booleans need to linked as preconditions to your iterator. If ticked on the iterator runs, if unticked (false) then the iterator does not run and anything downstream of it and connected wont run.

Comment: Downside is that stops everything from running, I want to only stop specific values from running. I think using the Calculate Value tool would allow me to take each value from the multivalue and compare it to the corresponding toggle on/off variable, but I don't know how I would write that

Comment: I think I finally figured out the Calculate Value tool with some Pythoncode to do a very basic if then, it's not pretty but it works